# filter by id in ndb model

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python, nosql

I am using ndb model as my databse. what i am trying to do is that filter the result on the basis of list of ids.
i have my model like :

```
class Photo(ndb.Model):
   userid = ndb.StringProperty()

   source = ndb.StringProperty()
   handle = ndb.StringProperty()
   sourceid =ndb.StringProperty()
```

So i am trying query like this:

```
              queryset=Photo.query(Photo.key.id().IN(photoid_list))
```

I have also tried :

```
              queryset=Photo.query(Photo.id().IN(photoid_list))
```

where photoid_list is the list of ids.
Help me out to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you create keys from each id and then get them all at once:

```
photo_keys = [ndb.Key(Photo, id) for id in photoid_list]
photos = ndb.get_multi(photo_keys)
```

The advantage is that a get is faster than a query.  Also, ndb will memcache the entities by key and make subsequent gets even faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There are examples in the docs:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in

So it looks like your query should be:

```py
queryset=Photo.query(Photo.id.IN(photoid_list))
```

Comment: It is showing  : Undefined variable from import  id